# User input method

Tags: java

I'm very new to this. I'm having problem creating a user input method. What I want is basically just a method that stores user input and quits if a letter "o" is entered. The input should only be integers but I don't want the program to crash if the user inputs a character or a floating number. This is what I got so far:

```
public static int userInput() 
{
    int number = 0;

    String r2 = "";
    System.out.println("enter number: ");

    while(input.hasNextInt() == true ){
        number = input.nextInt();
        if(r2.equals("Q") || r2.equals("q")){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;}
    }

    while(input.hasNextInt() != true ){         
        r2 = input.next();
        if(r2.equals("Q") || r2.equals("q")){
            return Integer.MAX_VALUE;}

    }
    return number;      
}
```

Appreciate any help I can get,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are multiple issues with this code. What is `input`? You're treating it as if it's a `Scanner` object, but you don't declare that in either your code or question. Furthermore, the variable `radie` is not declared. This should be caught by the compiler; you may have meant that to be `number` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I've rewritten your code and added comments explaining the areas you had issues in:

```
public static int userInput() {
    int number = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    /*
    * In this case, we want some value that indicates when the user decides not
    * to give input (typing "q")
    */
    String r2 = "";
    System.out.println("enter number: ");

    //we have to make input a Scanner object pointed at your input source
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    //The loops could be restructured into a single loop:
    boolean stay = true; //a variable to control the loop

    while (stay) {
        /*
        * In most cases, " x == true " is a redundant statement.
        * The comparison evaluates to a boolean, and if the first item
        * is already a boolean (or returns one), there is no need
        * to compare to true.
        */

        /*
        * For a slightly simpler way, simply get whatever the user inputs
        * and store that in a string. There's a way to test whether a
        * String contains characters that can be parsed into an int, as
        * well as a method to do such. We'll use r2 because you already
        * declared that as a String.
        */
        r2 = input.nextLine();
        boolean isNumber;

        //test whether r2 contains only number characters using try / catch
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(r2);
            isNumber = true;
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            isNumber = false;
        }

        /*
        * Now that that's been figured out, we run it through our tests
        * (converting to int if that's the case) and take action
        */
        if(isNumber) {
            number = Integer.parseInt(r2); //this will be returned
            stay = false;//no need to keep looping, we got what we came for.
        }
        else if(r2.toLowerCase().matches("q")) { //r2 is not int
            stay = false;// exit loop, Integer.MAX_VALUE will be returned
            //the code calling this function should be prepared to handle
            //that as a special case
        }
        else {
            //if it gets here, the input is neither an int nor "Q" nor "q"
            //better tell them to try again.
            System.out.println("Input invalid, try again.");
            System.out.println("enter number:");
        }


    }
    return number;
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: That helps a lot thanks! The problem now compared to before is that as soon as i enter a number the program terminates. I want it to keep on going until you press q

Comment: That helps a lot thanks! The problem now is that as soon as i enter a number the program terminates. I tried changing stay to true if its a number and it seems to work. The only problem I see now is that  if i enter for example "1 2 3 4" in one row, it says invalid number, I'm looking for it to return 1 through 4.

Comment: That would be a tad more difficult and you'd want to make another function that does comparisons and returns probably an int as a status code, since there would be three states that would need to be distinguished in this case: letter(s), number, numbers. At such a point the try/catch can't do everything for you and you'd have to change up that section of the code as well as write up something to parse space-separated integers (`str.split(' ')`, returns array of strings that were space-separated) in the handling part.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just doing an exercise for beginners java, so I don't think it has to be this advanced!